# Imperative with go (go do something )

Tags: imperative-sentences

I saw imperative sentences with the above-mentioned pattern with verbs "go", "come". The verbs are sometimes joined with "and". I understand it as informal usage with the first verb used as "encouragement" rather than "movement".

The question is:
- Can we use both patterns interchangeably?
- Can we use the to-infinitive as well?
- Can we use other verbs in this structure instead of "go","come"?

> Go and buy yourself a new pair of shoes.
>   Go buy yourself a new pair of shoes.
>   Go to buy yourself a new pair of shoes.

Comment: Go and buy... is definitely used in AmE, at least where I come from.

Comment: No, not encouragement, but movement. "Go and buy" is a compound verb phrase as part of the imperative. Same with "come and sit down". There are one or two other verbs: "Run and get me some milk before the store closes";

Comment: This is a very good question, and I always sought a good answer for such type of questions. I will provide some information regarding this later today.

Answer (score 2):

> [**Go** *and* **buy**] yourself a new dress.

Quirk et al. calls this sort of coordination *a pseudo-coordination*, while Biber et al. calls it by the name *coordinated binomial phrases*.

Biber et al. and Marriam Webster Dictionary of English usage further says that in American English that *and* is often left out when the verb before *and* in this construction is *go* or *come*.

> [**Go buy**] yourself a new dress.

Swan in his Practical English Usage says the similar things.

**SEMANTICS:**

Quirk et al and Marriam Webster dictionary of English Usage say that in this construction, the verb - *go* - looses its meaning of movement. And it's used mainly to emphasize the following verb (in this case it's *buy*).

Biber et al. says something different about its semantics. It says the verb *go* expresses "direction of action" and the second verb *buy* expresses the "consequent action to be accomplished".

Both Quirk et al. and Biber et al. says that such construction often expresses what it can express by a corresponding *to*-infinitive construction. For example -

> [**try** *and* **visit**] the temple at least once. --> **try** to **visit** the temple at least once.
>
> I will [**go** *and* **see**] him tomorrow --> I will **go see** him tomorrow --> I will **go** to **see** him tomorrow.

Further reading [here](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/005039.html).

Answer (score 0):

> - Can we use both patterns interchangeably?

Short Answer: I wouldn't, but this isn't to say you couldn't.

> - Can we use the to-infinitive as well?

Short Answer: I wouldn't, plus, I don't think it's correct grammatically.

> - Can we use other verbs in this structure instead of "go","come"?

Short Answer: Yes. And as @BillJ and @SantiBailors have both said, there are other verbs you could use, too.

Long Answer: The reason I wouldn't is because I think they sound different to the listener, or at least, they do to me.

That is, "Go and buy yourself a new pair of shoes"...

> ...sounds more polite and request-like than...

"Go buy yourself a new pair of shoes"...

> ...which sounds more like a command. Although, said very sweetly, this could sound nice and request-like as well, so in this respect, they could be used interchangeably.

What do you think? Do they sound different to you?

Comment: Thank you, could you give me any source to prove that using a to-infinitive after "go" is ungrammatical?

Comment: @V.V. Hmmm, for examples of imperatives such as yours, not off the top of my head, but honestly, this feels like [a case of presumption of innocence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presumption_of_innocence). Meanwhile, if you want to use "go + to infinitive" not as an imperative, there are lots of cases and examples.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't explain it to my students in the same way. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: @V.V. Perfect! Sounds like an excellent learning opportunity for your students, then.